# Pandas groupby two columns then get dict for values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
banned_titles = 
TitleId  RelatedTitleId
0    89989           32598
1    89989         3085083
2    95281         3085083
```

when I apply groupby as following

```
In [84]: banned_titles.groupby('TitleId').groups
Out[84]: {89989: [0, 1], 95281: [2]}
```

This is so close but not I want.

What I want is:

```
{89989: [32598, 3085083], 95281: [3085083]}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this:

```
In [8]: x.groupby('TitleId')['RelatedTitleId'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()
Out[8]: {89989: [32598, 3085083], 95281: [3085083]}
```

or as series of lists:

```
In [10]: x.groupby('TitleId')['RelatedTitleId'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[10]:
TitleId
89989    [32598, 3085083]
95281           [3085083]
Name: RelatedTitleId, dtype: object
```

data:

```
In [9]: x
Out[9]:
   TitleId  RelatedTitleId
0    89989           32598
1    89989         3085083
2    95281         3085083
```

Comment: Sweet! Just what I wanted, lightning fast response. Дякую!

Answer (score 4):

Try list one line (no lambda):

```
dict(df.groupby('TitleId')['RelatedTitleId'].apply(list))
 # {89989: [32598, 3085083], 95281: [3085083]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I believe this no longer works in pandas 21

Comment: Do you know how to save keynames from the DataFrame to the dict?