# Use dict aggregation in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1' : [ 1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3,   3,   4,   4],
    'key2' : ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'e'],
    'value' : [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   10]
})
```

[I could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690092/pandas-groupby-two-columns-then-get-dict-for-values) use `list` to aggregate the columns:

```
dat.groupby('key1')['key2'].apply(list)
## key1
## 1          [a, b]
## 2          [a, c]
## 3    [b, c, d, e]
## 4          [c, e]
## Name: key2, dtype: object
```

What if I wanted to obtain an aggregate grouped by `key1`, where each row is a `dict` of `{ key2 : value }` pairs? My expected output is:

```
## key1
## 1          {a : 1, b : 2}
## 2          {a : 3, c : 4}
## 3    {b : 5, c : 6, d : 7, e : 8}
## 4          {c : 9, e : 10}
```

How can this be achieved in pandas?

One solution could be to create two lists using the function above and then combine them as `dict`, but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `df.groupby('key1')['key2', 'value'].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))`

Comment: @coldspeed I updated. And YES, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, you're looking for `groupby` + `apply`.

```
df.groupby('key1')['key2', 'value'].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))

key1
1                    {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
2                    {'a': 3, 'c': 4}
3    {'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 7, 'e': 8}
4                   {'c': 9, 'e': 10}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you comment on why `.apply(lambda x : dict(x))` does not work? I was trying to achieve your solution step-by-step, but the error has stopped me to finding it by myself...

Comment: @Tim `.apply(lambda x : x)` is like saying 1 = 1, it does nothing - the output is identical to the input. You need to aggregate it somehow, that's what `dict` does there.

Comment: Hard to think of an alternative